# name not resolve in vmware client PC

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, vmware-workstation, nslookup

I have configured DNS server and DHCP sever on centos 6.2 vmware virtual machine. I have a windows xp vmware client machine.

nslookup command is work in server terminal But it won't work in windows xp machine
I checked my DHCP server assign correct ip address to my xp client is there additional configurations to make nslookup work in client side?

My server ip is 192.168.0.10

This is how client get ip drom my DHCP server

```
 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapt

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-41-6E-9D
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.128
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, June 03, 2013 3:51:34 PM
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, June 04, 2013 3:51:34 AM
```

This is the output of client nslookup

```
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.10: Timed out
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.10

DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Comment: so on the xp client do an ipconfig /all are the dns settings correct?

Comment: yes when I do  ipconfig /all DNS server IP display

Comment: from xp can you ping the dns servers?

Comment: yes i can ping to my server

Comment: Make sure server's firewall is off or allow DNS traffic.

Comment: can you telnet to the ipaddress on port 53, as in "telnet 192.168.0.10 53"

Comment: I can't telnet. I don't think there is firewall in centos because i didn't configure such a thing

Comment: whats the interface config  on the centos device, same subnet mask etc..

Comment: 50 % solved enabled DNS from fire wall now dns resolve for local server when i type www.google.com it does not resolve But it resolve in server terminal

Comment: ya need to forward the requests somewhere!

Comment: some where means I have configured my ISP DNS as secondary dns server in resolve conf is that not enough ? I can resolve google facebook ebay any web address from server terminal

Comment: so if you do an nslookup www.google.com from the xp workstation does it time out.

Comment: yes it time out

Comment: here's the XP nslookup output   ======Server:  dns.sithila.server
Address:  192.168.0.10

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to dns.sithila.server timed-out=====